# Show the difference of two consecutive vertical chart lines between the two lines

Tags: scichart

I use a SciChartSurface object in WPF. The chart shows many horizontal and vertical lines in a specified range. Now, I wand to display additional data between two vertical lines. The data to be displayed is the difference of the two lines values (red labels in the attached picture).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in SciChart to display two rows of axis, however you can display anything on the chart itself right at the bottom using the Annotations API.

Consider using a TextAnnotation with CoordinateMode.RelativeY, and set Y1=0.0. Also set VerticalAnchorPoint.Bottom to bottom align.

```
<s:SciChartSurface>
 .. 
    <s:SciChartSurface.Annotations>
        <s:TextAnnotation HorizontalAnchorPoint="Center" VerticalAnchorPoint="Bottom"
                          CoordinateMode="RelativeY" Y1="0.0"
                          X1="123.4" 
                          Text="{Binding Path=X1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    </s:SciChartSurface.Annotations>
</s:SciChartSurface>
```

This will display a text annotation at X=123.4 at the bottom of the chart, centred on that value.